# Simple query on a dataset of 2.5 million records

Tags: xml, excel, ms-access, csv, offline

I've got a dataset (id, reference) stored in comma separated text file, Each ID is associated with 1 of 5 references. e.g.

```
1B3242MK,A 
2C003212KL,S
L001DH728,A
```

I have a web version of a tool using php and MySQL that when you type in an id will return a web address based on the reference. eg.

```
A,google.com
C,bbc.co.uk
L,twitter.com
R,facebook.com
S,instagram.com
```

What I need to do is create a standalone version for offline use. I had set up an excel spreadsheet where the user enters the ID and is return the URL via a VLOOKUP in a VLOOKUP but unfortunately excel will only handle 1,048,000 rows and at the moment the dataset is 2.2million rows (and 30Mb).

I can't be sure that the end users will have access, but I was wondering whether I could, through access, export as XML and then query through a browser.

Any idea how I could do this??

Comment: You could probably use Windows PowerShell for this to query the recordset and pipe it to the export-clixml cmdlet. I wouldn't want to hack a guess at the code though as I'm a bit rusty on PowerShell

Comment: Could save it as an XML file and use a binary search of the dom assuming the XML is sorted by ID.  User enters Id and in a loop it would find the record and reference in about 20 tries. however 2.5 million records offline... taking some space...

Answer (score 1):

Given the number of rows you have, i dont see excel or XML solving your problem.

Id consider creating a simple program with embedded Sqlite/hsqldb to tackle this problem. You need an efficient index to perform the query for speed reasons, so using a database would be your best option.

Write a program that will batch insert your data and store it in a file. Set up your program to take the db filename as argument so you can use multiple of these file databases for your testing and actual use.

I would set this up as 2 tables, the same way as described by you and keep the ID as the key(assuming it  is unique).

Now you should be able to write a program to accept and ID, query the database and display the result with decent performance.

HTH

Comment: Note he could do the same with an Access MDB format database from any version of Windows regardless of whether or not Access itself is installed as long as the data will be retrieved via a 32 bit process.

Comment: With HSQLDB, you can open the CVS file direct as an SQL table, add in-memory indexes and query it with SQL. The actual data is still read from the CVS file on demand

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, we could work around the row limit:

1. Split your huge database in two or more parts, using some efficient criteria to separate rows (this is basically a hash function, see below).
2. Let's say you got 3 parts, put them in 3 separate worksheets.
3. Turn your VLOOKUP command into three commands, one for each sheet, and use a couple of IF's to point to the correct sheet

   Pseudo-code:

   `IF(group1, (VLOOKUP on Sheet1), IF(group2, (VLOOKUP on Sheet2), (VLOOKUP on Sheet3)))`

To select which condition to use, to split your data (and then find it), you have to experiment. I would start with a separation by first character, something like this:

```
ID's starting with digits or letters A to F go in group 1
ID's starting with letters G-Q go in group 2
ID's starting with letters R to Z go in group 3
```

See if this makes a balanced hash function for your data (giving fairly equal groups), or else tweak it to your liking (using the 2nd character instead of the first, for example).

Performance tip: if your data is static, sort it in Excel, and use VLOOKUPs with the forth parameter `is_sorted` set to TRUE. with so many rows, this should make a huge difference.